# Как вывести в датах "сегодня" и "вчера"?

Tags: php

Есть вывод новостей списком, вида:

- Новость 1 / Сегодня, 06:34
- Новость 2 / Сегодня, 23:21
- Новость 3 / Сегодня, 21:56

Как мне сделать так, чтобы вместо "сегодня" во 2 и 3 новости писалось "Вчера"?
Сейчас вывод выглядит так:

```
echo $r['title'];
echo ' / Сегодня, ';
echo date('H:i', $r['date']);
```

Дата в формате `1580067424`

Comment: очевидно, необходимо сравнить дату (без времени) новости со вчерашней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо сравнивать с сегодняшней датой Ваши даты. 
Пример:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

$today = date('d');// Получаем сегодняшний день
$r = array('title' => "Новость 1", "date" => "1580067324");
echo $r['title'];
if (date('d', $r['date']) < $today){ //Сравниваем день даты и сегодняшний день, если меньше, то Выводим "Вчера"
    echo ' / вчера, ';
} else {
    echo ' / Сегодня, ';
}
echo date('H:i', $r['date']);
```

Comment: По сути, данный ответ полностью решает мою задачу. А можно ли добавить в него еще 1 условие, чтобы, если опубликовано 2 дня назад, писалось, например "25 янв в 10:30"?

Comment: @Stop-TussiN Да, можно добавить множество условий.